# Cannot a second photon strike the electron that has been excited by the first?

Tags: speed-of-light, photoelectric-effect

Suppose during the photoelectric effect experiment, an electron gets hit by a photon whose frequency is less the threshold frequency of the metallic surface. It will get excited, but we know that it will not be ejected out and will return to its ground state.

Now, during the return journey, if a second photon strikes the electron ( it can because an excited electron takes about 10^-9 second to return back and in that time, a photon can travel about 10 to 100 cm), will the electron be ejected.

By experiments we know that it will not, but can we show it logically.

Comment: Multi-photon photoelectric effect is known, and addressed in various questions on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the energy of a photon is high enough to knock out the metal, it doesn't matter where the electron is.

The probability of the event described by OP is very low, yet the event itself is not formidable.